# How to say ,"Stand up for yourself" and "take advantage of"

Tags: phrase-requests

I have a younger friend that I want to use these kind of expressions with, but don't know how to say it in Japanese. I want them to do their best and not have people take advantage of them. I feel they might be the kind of person, that would take negative things from other people to their detriment. So, I want to say something like, you have to stand up for yourself sometimes. If you don't people will take advantage of you. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You have to stand up for yourself sometimes. If you don't, people will take advantage of you.
>
> You should stand up for yourself and not have people take advantage of you.

How about...

「（ときには）[自己主張]{じこしゅちょう}しなくちゃいけないよ。そうでないと、人につけこまれるから。」

「自分の[意見]{いけん}ははっきり言わないといけないよ。そうしないと、[足下]{あしもと}を見られるよ。」

or maybe...

「[黙]{だま}っていちゃだめだよ。でないと、つけこまれるだけだよ。」

Answer (score 0):

The direct and harsh translation of "Don't take advantage of someone! Stand up for yourseld" is "人に頼るな!　自分でやれ！"
I'm not sure the situation, but I believe you don't want to fail at the relationship. So "人に頼らないで、自分でやってみよう！" shoule be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

Don't let anyone take advantage of you, stand up yourself, u can do it: 他の人に優しさを利用させないで。自分で立ち上がれ、あなたの力を信じる。